# how to store future data while loading app for further use ? # Flutter

Tags: android, database, android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout

**I'm new to flutter.** I am trying to make an app for myself which can do some calculations for me.

1. **The Situation:** When I start the app it starts with the loading screen. While loading it make an API call to get some data which I
   will need in the future. And send it to the pages where I need it. This is working fine.
2. **The problem:** I have multiple pages in the app. When I return from any other page to the main page the data got vanished. So I
   have to make another API call to get the data back. And I don't want
   this to happen
3. **What I want:** I want that when the data is received it should be stored somewhere locally so that I can use it wherever I want, without making another API call or without an internet connection.

**[Check the video demo here to understand better](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YA7P0HNLjaV9SRuM9AWmstpb6hDqvxjg/view?usp=sharing)**

**What I am doing:**

**Loading screen:**

```
class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}

class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {
 void setupPair() async 
{
    CurrInfo instance =
    CurrInfo(url: 'EUR/USD', flagA: 'eur.png', flagB: 'usd.png');

    await instance.getInfo();

   if (instance.price != "not connected") 
   {
     Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home', arguments: {
        'url': instance.url,
        'flagA': instance.flagA,
        'flagB': instance.flagB,
        'price': instance.price,
     });  
  }                       // I don't want to send this instance, instead I want to store the Received 
                             data locally and access that data from anywhere inside the app
 
 Video else if (instance.price == "not connected") {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/not connected');
    }
}
```

**Getting data by making api call:**

```
class CurrInfo {
String url;
String flagA;
String flagB;
String price;
String furl;
Map data;
List info;

 CurrInfo({this.url, this.flagA, this.flagB});

 Future<void> getInfo() async {
  try {
  print((url));
  furl =
      "https://fcsapi.com/api-v2/forex/latest? 
       symbol=$url&access_key=t58zo1uMFJZlNJxSrSmZv2qIUlSkCk9RAfCLkwnMwt1q1FFS";
 
    Response response = await http
      .get(Uri.encodeFull(furl), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(data);

    info = data['response'];
    print(info);

    price = info[0]['price'];  // I want to save this price data locally while loading so that I 
                                 don't have to make another API call to get it back and it should be 
                                 updated when I refresh the page

    print("string price : $price");
    } catch (e) {
    price = "not connected";
    print('error is : $e &  $price');
  
    }}}
```

**How i'm using this data where i need :**

```
Map data = {};
String ofData;



 Expanded(flex: 1,
      child: Text( ${data['url']}',
      style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 25,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
      ),
     ),
    
     Expanded( flex: 1,
       child: Text('${data['price']}',
       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
       textAlign: TextAlign.end,
      ),
    ),
```

**[Check out full code here to understand better](https://github.com/hiimaanshu/Easy-Pips/tree/main)**

Comment: you can use SQlite or Floor to save your data in local storage. you can find more on floor here :- https://pub.dev/packages/floor

Comment: Have you tried googling about how to to store data locally ? There are tons fo articles and tutorials

Comment: I thought there may be a simpler way to achieve this. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What can be a simpler way then googling your problem by yourself ? Please try to find solutions by yourself and if you stuck anywhere with implementations then post your questions and definitely someone will help you out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+2 to store data locally on phone

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences    link to the package